# Component being re-rendered even if the corresponding record is unchanged - Vue JS, Vuex ORM

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-orm

I have an application on Vue JS that receives the data from the server via WebSocket and renders the changes. I am using Vuex ORM for defining entities in the store. The problem I am facing is that if an update is received that has changes for a record with id 1, the component that is rendered for the record with id 2 is re-rendered (which, in principle, should not because the record it is bound to has not been updated).

My component looks like this,

`<UserDetail :userId="userId" :key="userId" />`

Inside the component, there is a computed property that looks like this

```
computed: {
   User(){ // User property is attached to the UI 
    return UserEntity.find(this.userId);
   }
}
```

The structure of UserEntity is simple, it has five data fields and no relations to any other entity. The data in the UserEntity is added whenever there is an update on the connected WebSocket.

I tried adding a :key to the component because I read that keys control the rendering behavior of the components but that did not work.

Looking forward to any help!

Comment: how does your Vuex store looks like and how yout mutations and how do you call the mutations? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: In Vuex-ORM, all entities are registered in the vuex store as a separate module. Vuex-ORM provides methods over entities that eliminate the need of defining actions and mutations i.e. UserEntity.insert(), UserEntity.delete()

https://vuex-orm.org/

Comment: so `UserEntity` is your vuex and `find` a getter? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: Yes.That is it.

Comment: This is just the way Vuex ORM is implemented. It does not make use of Vue internals such as `Vue.set` etc so when it updates the store, it replaces the entire data for the entity rather than patching the specific record. Sadly, there is no workaround for this.

Comment: @Cue Learned this the hard way! Ended up ditching the Vuex ORM and listened to the particular update (to the specific record from the store) in the component.

Comment: Vuex ORM isn’t necessarily fit for every purpose but I’m glad to hear you found a solution that works for you!